# Haskell: Creating record of list of string and pair of <string and list of string>

Tags: haskell, winghci

How to create a record of list of string and, pair of  in Haskell

I tried  the following

For creating a record of list of string

```
data testList = test [string]
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

When I run it, it gives me the following error

> Not a data constructor: `test'

For creating a record of pair of

```
data testList = test (String,[string])
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

It also gives the same error

> Not a data constructor: `test'

can anyone explain me the problem and solution for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first letter of data types must be a capital letter.
[wikipedia/haskell/type declarations](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Type_declarations)

Comment: Try, `data TestList = Test String [String]`